# Spring Webflux Flux<List<MyPojo>> to Flux<MyPojo>

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding how to convert a Flux<List> to Flux in Spring Webflux.

I tried some combinations of reduce and flat map, but not getting the Flux .

If it is possible, what would be the correct way to get a Flux from Flux<List> please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMapIterable`:

```java
Flux<List<MyPojo>> myFlux = ...
myFlux.flatMapIterable(p -> p).map(myPojo -> ...)
```

See the documentation for `flatMapIterable` [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapIterable-java.util.function.Function-).